# Practical application of EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN to find addresses for delivery

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Our end users have many ways of shipping product to our customers. They can use the customer address in one table (`[customer]`), a specific delivery address in another (`[dropship]`), or yet another delivery address in another table (for customers with multiple locations) (`[delivery]`). These all have roughly the same structure, with the same column names for the same data points (e.g. `[address]` is the address in all tables).

Currently, our logic for finding the delivery address of an order is as follows:

```
SELECT
    Address = COALESCE(r.address, d.address, c.address) 
FROM [order] o 
JOIN customer c
    ON o.customerid = c.customerid
LEFT JOIN delivery d
    ON o.customerid = d.customerid
    AND o.delivaddressid = d.delivaddress
LEFT JOIN dropship r
    ON o.orderid = r.orderid;
```

Based on conversations and [not](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) a few [blog posts](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/), `EXISTS` seems to be preferred.

However, this is a new paradigm to me and I'm trying to wrap my brain around it. Do I just replace the `LEFT JOIN`s with

```
WHERE EXISTS 
    (select 1 from delivery d
        where o.customerid = d.customerid 
        and o.delivaddressid = d.delivaddress)
```

This won't allow me to use the data from `[delivery]` unless I toss it in the `FROM` clause and create a cartesian product, right?

Comment: If you actually need to return the address from one of those tables, you can't use `EXISTS`. Is there any room here for improved design (e.g. a single Addresses table with type)? You'll still need to include that table but it will be a much more digestible query.

Comment: If you want only one column (the `address`) from a left joined table you could use an inline subquery (2 for getting the columns from the 2 tables) and the `FROM` clause would be a bit cleaner (only `customer` and `order`). But it would probably yield different execution plan and I doubt it would be more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can use `EXISTS` to determine whether, say, a dropship address is present, you can't use it to tell what the actual address is. `EXISTS` doesn't return any data. For that, you'll need the join.

A better design might be well-served here, for example a single `Addresses` table with a type. But as I understand it your model is currently not flexible.